# How to change as logout in navbar after successful login in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I am new to React js, I have tried to Build Login page in react js with navbar all went fine but when I have change the logout from login in navbar after successful login I was struck. I have tried multiple ways but none of the ways worked. Can anyone please help me solve my issue.

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css'
import UserPage from './UserPage';

function Login(props) {

    let navi = useNavigate();
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [message, setMessage] = useState();
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(0);


    const database = [
        {
            name: "piranesh",
            password: "12"
        }
    ];

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const userData = database.find((n) => n.name === name);
        if (userData) {
            if (userData.password === password) {
                setLoggedIn(1);
                navi('/userprofile');
            }
            else {
                setMessage("Invalid username or Password");
            }
        }
        else {
            setMessage("Invalid username or Password");
        }
        setName("");
        setPassword("");


    }
    return (
        <div style={{ paddingTop: "150px" }}>
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h3>{message}</h3>
                <table className="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th><label >User Name : </label></th>
                        <th><input type="text" name="name" value={name} placeholder="Enter your user name" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} /><br /></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label >Password : </label></th>
                        <th><input type="password" name="password" value={password} placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} /><br /></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><button type="submit">Log in</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>


        </div>

    );
}

export default Login;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Login from './Login';
import UserPage from './UserPage';

function Header(props) {


    return (

        <div>

            <BrowserRouter>
                <Link to="/" style={{ paddingRight: '60px', paddingLeft: '950px' }}>Home</Link>
                <Link to="/about" style={{ paddingRight: '60px' }}>About</Link>
                <Link to="/login" style={{ paddingRight: '60px' }}>Login</Link>

                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
                    <Route path='/userprofile' element={<UserPage />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>


    )
};


export default Header;
```

UserPage.js

```
import React from 'react';



function UserPage(props) {

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Hello this is User Page </h1>
        </div>
    )
};

export default UserPage;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './components/Header';


function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
 
}

export default App;
```

Thanks

Comment: You'd want to set up a global `App`-level state to check whether the user is logged in, and conditionally render `Login` or `Logout`. That is, if `!loggedIn`, show `Log In` that routes to `/login` to handle authentication. If `loggedIn`, show `Log Out` instead which handles signing out.

Comment: Having said the above, I'd assume this is for learning purposes only, as proper login/logout flow has to involve more than plain text for data persistence. For real life use cases, I'd recommend 3rd party auth services like Auth0, Netlify Identity, Firebase Auth, etc, which are intuitive to use and battle-tested.

Comment: Thanks @Bumhan can you please give me a small code snippet on how to set up a global App-level state.

Comment: There are a few different ways to achieve it: using `useState` in `App` component to drill into child components, using `context` API which can be accessed anywhere in component tree, or using a state management dependency. I'd recommend you do a basic research about `React global state` for more.